# Vim split terminal not opening as expected

Tags: neovim

I was using terminal inside neovim with ''':vsplit term''' and I closed it with ZZ. After that ''':vsplit term''' opens as an empty file. Although ''':terminal''' opens a new terminal as expected. Any solutions to get split terminal back?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Removed the vim tag because this has nothing to do with Vim.

Answer (score 1):

"term" is valid file name.

If you mean `:term` command you must execute `:vsplit +term` or `:vsplit term://bash` and such.